# Load same Angular controller twice in template, but without second AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I've inherited a new Angular project and found some odd repeated AJAX requests occurring on every page. I've found this is because in the template there are a couple of ng-include's to template assets in the header and footer.

These includes use the same controller (ItemController) which makes a request to pull a list of user items. It then displays info based on those items in both the header and footer. Ideally, this should just happen once on page load (regardless of the number of times the controller is used).

Is there some way to share a controller between two templates (header and footer)? Or does anyone have any advise for how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to share a controller between templates. That is to say, two templates can use the same controller, but there will be two separate instances of the controller.

The controllers should be calling a service which handles the retrieval of data. This is basic Angular.

A service is a singleton. It is instantiated only once per run of your Angular app. I good way to prevent multiple AJAX calls from going out is to store the results of the ajax call in the service, or use a cache. That way many controllers can request the data, but only one AJAX call needs to be made.

An optional parameter can be passed to invalidate the cache if there is a need to get fresh data.

```
function DataService($http, $q, apiUrl) {
  var DataService = this;
  var data = [];
  var promiseKeeper = {};

  DataService.getData = function(invalidateCache) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(data.length > 0 && !invalidateCache) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
    else {
      if(promiseKeeper["getData"]) {
        return promiseKeeper["getData"];
      }
      else {
        $http.get(apiUrl)
          .then(function(response) {
            data = response.data;
            promiseKeeper["getData"] = undefined;
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
          });
        promiseKeeper["getData"] = deferred.promise;
        return promiseKeeper["getData"];
      }
   }
}
```

The `promiseKeeper` object will handle multiple requests for data when the `data` parameter has not yet been populated. When you have several controllers requesting the same data at almost the same time, this makes them all wait on the same promise to be resolved instead of creating multiple promises for each request.